# Determining a single statement in a conditional statement is true

Tags: c

I have a number of signals that can be true, false or invalid, but only one of these can be true otherwise it is an error.

I want to know if there is a way to check for this easily rather than needing to do a large if statement

```
enum sig_type
{
  sig_invalid, sig_true, sig_false
};

sig_type sig1 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig2 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig3 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig4 = GetSignal("sig1");

if (sig1 == sig_true)
{
  if (sig2 == sig_true || sig3 == sig_true || sig4 == sig_true)
  {
    // Error
  }
}
else if (sig2 == sig_true)
{
  if (sig1 == sig_true || sig3 == sig_true || sig4 == sig_true)
  {
    // Error
  }
}
```

etc... Which is a significant amount of code and only increases as I add signals so in this state is going to be unmanageable

Comment: Do you mean that **exactly** one of them **has to be** true?

Comment: Do you treat each `// Error` section equally or do you have to do a different thing each time ?

Comment: It appears that bit manipulation might help.

Comment: Exactly one can be true, any more is an error. I also do do the same for each section

Comment: What about changing the function `GetSignal`? It could count the calls where a `sig_true` has been returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fact that logical expressions in C evaluate to 0 for false or 1 for true, and sum these together.  If the total is greater than 1, you have an error, otherwise you don't.

Separately, if you think you might need more (or just a variable number of) signals in future, I'd use an array to hold them instead of separate variables.  Then the test can be done inside a `for` loop:

```
sig_type sig[NSIGNALS];
int t = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < NSIGNALS; ++i) {
    char buf[50];   /* Make sure your buffer is large enough, of course */
    sprintf(buf, "sig%d", i + 1);    /* Or however you want to generate it */
    sig[i] = GetSignal(buf);
    t += sig[i] == sig_true;
}

if (t > 1) {
    /* Complain */
}
```

If you meant that exactly 1 signal must be true, replace the `t > 1` test with `t != 1`.

**EDIT:** Originally had a `throw` in the error handler, though that's not C.

Comment: I don't know if this adapts well to his current if statements or if those are just an example.

Comment: If fetching *all* the signals is *not* required (i.e. as soon as you detect more than one is set you can bail), then add `&& t <= 1` to the loop condition. I've no idea if the OP's signal fetch is mandated to clear some hardware port regardless of usage, but if not, early bailout seems plausible.

Comment: Once you have the loop, you don't need the 'boolean arithmetic' trick.   `bool oneTrue = false; for(...) { if (condition) { if (oneTrue) /* Complain */ else oneTrue = true; }}`

Comment: @Roddy: That's true if WhozCraig is right and it's OK to stop as soon as we know there will be an error (which is what I'd expect). In fact, even if all calls to `GetSignal()` *must* take place then similar logic could still be used to avoid "boolean arithmetic", though I think there's no real gain to doing so.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Indeed. Probably just a matter of which version you'd find easier to read two years down  the road!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to solve this in obscure, ineffective and needlessly complicated ways.

Either store all signals in an array, or if that isn't possible, store an array of pointers to them as below:

```
const sig_type* sigs [number_of_sig] = 
{
  &sig1,
  &sig2,
  ...
};
```

Then iterate through this array.

```
bool one_sig_true = false;

for(int i=0; i<number_of_sig; i++)
{
  if(*sigs[i] == sig_true)
  {
    if(one_sig_true)    // if one was already true from before
    {
      error();
      break;
    }

    one_sig_true = true; // otherwise, set this flag
  }
}

// if the loop finished without error, everything is fine
```

Comment: That looks very like my comment on @j_random_hacker's answer.. ;-)

Comment: @Roddy Indeed. I didn't see your comment, I only read the present answers and found them unappealing at various degrees. You should have posted as an answer instead of a comment, then I would have up-voted you :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, using this in conjunction with @j_random_hacker gave me the solution I required.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple trick for asserting that a given `value` has more than a single bit set to 1:

```
value & (value-1)
```

Here is how you can use this trick in order to achieve your goal with a single `if` statement:

```
enum sig_type
{
    sig_inv   = 0,
    sig_true  = 1,
    sig_false = 2,
};

int b0 = (int)GetSignal("sig1") & 1;
int b1 = (int)GetSignal("sig1") & 1;
int b2 = (int)GetSignal("sig1") & 1;
int b3 = (int)GetSignal("sig1") & 1;

int value = (b0<<0) | (b1<<1) | (b2<<2) | (b3<<3);
if (value & (value-1))
{
    // Error
}
```

Comment: +1 for a neat trick. -1 for not explaining it well, and the scary macros!

Comment: I'd favour @harper's solution instead of this macro mess. It is the very same solution, except his version is readable. Also, converting something to `int` before applying bit-wise operators isn't a good idea. Use an unsigned type instead.

Comment: @Lundin: The `int` is casted from `sig_type`, which can only retain the values of 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: @Roddy: Thanks for pointing that out. Added an explanation and removed the macro...

Answer (score 1):

just make your code memorize the "state" in a variable.

```
enum sig_type
{
    sig_invalid, sig_true, sig_false
};

sig_type sig1 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig2 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig3 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig4 = GetSignal("sig1");

int count = 0;

if (sig1 == sig_true) {
    count++;
}
if (sig2 == sig_true) {
    count++;
}
if (sig3 == sig_true) {
    count++;
}
if( sig4 == sig_true) {
    count++;
}

if (count > 1) {
    /* your error code here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a solution with arithmetic. I has the benefit, that you get a good place for the valid cases too. Further you don't need any loop that could flush your instruction pipeline.

```
enum sig_type
{
  sig_invalid, sig_true, sig_false
};

sig_type sig1 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig2 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig3 = GetSignal("sig1");
sig_type sig4 = GetSignal("sig1");

// This can be rewritten as needed and the personal preferences. 
// The arithmetic that is described in this answer remains.
int cumulative_result = 
    ((sig1 == sig_true) << 0) |
    ((sig2 == sig_true) << 1) |
    ((sig3 == sig_true) << 2) |
    ((sig4 == sig_true) << 3));

switch (cumulative_result)
{
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
case 4:
case 8:
    break;
default:
    /* your error code here */
    break;
}
```

You can be more specific for cases that are "more evil" as well.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the OP is interested in all combinations. And needless to say, an enum or `#define` should be instead of the magic numbers.

Comment: OP says that one signal **can be** true, not **has to be** true, so `case 0` is missing in your solution.

Comment: @Lundin This approach gives you all combinations and it gives you a convenient way to ignore them. Needless to say that you can make anything less readable with macros and this answer just shows the way not the final code.